# No boot priority options in bios

Tags: boot, bios

My system is displaying just the following message on a black screen : "Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media in selected boot device and press a key"

When I enter the advanced BIOS features to check boot device priority,  no boot priority options are there i.e no first boot device, second soon.

What could be the reason(s)? How can I fix it?

[image: [This is the screenshot for advanced bios features]]

[image]

Update : the question that has beeen proposed as a duplicate for this is different as the user is at least getting the boot device select option there however in my case I don't get any boot device select option inside advanced bios features menu. See the first screenshot.

Comment: What is the make and model of your motherboard?

Comment: Mercury motherboard, assembled CPU

Comment: (sigh) And the model number?

Comment: I guess will have to open the cabinet for that. Any pointers as to what could be the possible reasons for this. Is this out of norm or happens usually?

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik please see the update.